# Exception occurs for hash character in Dollar quote with JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using [Dollar quote](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) (i.e. `$xx$`) for my query and getting Exception when the input has a hash character(`#`) inside.

```
select * from tbl_abc where col_x = $xx$#$xx$
                                        ^
```

The Exception is:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
Error Code: 0
Call: select * from tbl_abc where col_x = $xx$?
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

I can see there a `?` character in the error message, but I didn't have that in my query. Here is my java code:

```
String query = "select * from tbl_abc where col_x = $xx$#$xx$";
Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query, Abc.class);
List<Abc> abcList = nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

FYI: it works smoothly when I use `'#'` instead of `$xx$#$xx$`. Also my query runs nicely from the `postgres` console.

How can I escape that `#` character for Dollar quote from JPA?

I am using `Java` with `Eclipselink` and the database is `Postgres`.

Comment: Not an answer but... what's the point of using this syntax? Why not use a parameterized query, and pass the unquoted string as a parameter? The JDBC driver will quote the parameter for you.

Comment: Does this query work with plain JDBC? If not, this is totally unrelated to Eclipselink and might be a JDBC driver issue.